# What is consumer_key and consumer_secret being use in tweepy?

Tags: twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v2

I can't even find any clue about it in Twitter Developer dashboard, I look at the API key and the only word use there 'api_key', 'api_key_secret', 'access_token', 'access_token_secret', 'bearer_token', 'client_id' and 'client_secret'.

Anyone please explain this

I googled for that specific term but there's NONE exact word like that. Can I know what is 'consumer_key' and 'consumer_secret' being use here as tweepy API reference?

I even tried to use client_id and client_secret as replacement for consumer_key and consumer_secret, but still got error 'cannot authenticate'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't use tweepy but considering that these are auth1.0 names it should be as follows:
`consumer_key`: the same as `api_key`
`consumer_secret`: the same as `api_key_secret`